# compilerMetadata is modifying/artifacts/NAME_OF_CONTRACT.json

Tags: remix, compiler, warnings

I have been getting a compiler warning in the online remix IDE that is not quite clear to me (the contract compiles and deploys without any errors):

compilerMetadata is modifying/artifacts/NAME_OF_CONTRACT.json

Does anyone know what might be causing this? The debugger threw this cryptic error:

creation of NAME_OF_CONTRACT errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.1.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.1.2)

Although there is not address provided (its in the constructor)

Comment: I would be interested in hearing if anyone knows about this as well. I have been getting the same error, but it is listing the interface that I am using to interact with a token contract.
My contract compiles and deploys without issues. All functions work as intended. But I can't publish and verify the contract on etherscan.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal contract that produced such error message?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to **UNCHECK** the **Generate contract metadata.** from the setting as @Akrramo mentioned otherwise if you UNCHECK the **Auto compile** then you have to compile the code every time you do some modifications.

Answer (score 0):

In COMPILER CONFIGURATION uncheck the box: "Auto compile".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting in the bottom of the page General settings
and uncheck 'Generate contract metadata.'

Comment: What do I lose / gain from having or not having contract metadata?